# How can I pack different lists and dicts into a single JSON object in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a set of different lists and dictionaries and variables.

Can I pack them all into one JSON object? 
How would you go about it?
Call `json.dumps()` on each of them and then somehow put them together?

My purpose behind this is to make the data available to my JavaScript program via an `npm` python shell.

Comment: Can you put some code to better explain?

Comment: You could add all your data to a `dict` and dump that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put all your individual lists and dicts into one big dictionary and `json.dumps` that dictionary. You could use the variable names as keys, or just put them all one after the other in a list.

```
>>> a_list = [1,2,3]
>>> a_dict = {"foo": 42, "bar": [4,5,6]}
>>> import json
>>> everything = {"a_list": a_list, "a_dict": a_dict}
>>> json.dumps(everything)
'{"a_list": [1, 2, 3], "a_dict": {"foo": 42, "bar": [4, 5, 6]}}'
```